# PolSARPro giving error messages after fresh install

Tags: tcl

I am trying to open PolSARPro after a fresh install and receive the error message:

```
can't read "Version": no such variable
 while executing
"append PSPEnd $Version"
  (Procedure "InitPolSARproENV" line 25)
  invoked from within
"InitPolSARproENV"
  (procedure "init" line 521)
  invoked from within
"init $argc $argv"
  file "C:/Program Files/PolSARpro_v4.2.0/PolSARpro_v4.2.0.tcl" line 12328.
```

Comment: If PolSARPro is not a program you created, you might get more help by contacting the party who created it. Otherwise, this is not an appropriate question for StackOverflow.

Comment: It looks like the variable `Version` is not set (and so can't be read, of course). There is no indication why this is so, and the program is not just a standard Tcl program (_tclsh_ or _wish_) so we can't do much to assist. Contact the vendor/author for support.

Answer (score 0):

You have this message because you need to install TCL/TK, a prerequesite of polsarpro.

There is a free community version that can be downloaded [here](https://www.activestate.com/products/activetcl/downloads/). After installing tcl-tk, make sure that .tcl files are associated with this software.